# compile timed out

Tags: compiling, sharelatex

I hope you can help me, I'm so depressed. 
When I try to compile my report it show me the message posted below. How can I solve this problem please? [image]

Comment: Without a minimal example code  reproducing the problem, it's hard to help!

Comment: Either your document is really too large for sharelatex, or there is an error in it that leads to some loop or something else which gives a time out.

Comment: @Bernard how can I post my code please?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There are no emty line in my document, I tried to delete all of them

Comment: Have you tried compiling it locally?

Comment: empty line?? I wrote about errors not empty lines.

Comment: @AlexanderWilms What did you mean by "locally? I work into a site "sharelatex" I didn't download  the software (mikex and texeditor)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I saw somwhere in the net, to avoid loop you have to delet  blank  line in your code

Comment: If you install a distribution and editor on your computer, you are not restricted regarding the time it takes to compile your document.

Comment: @hayfou: Maybe you can post a link to your code.

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=27298)

Comment: Almost all `.tex` files *should* contain blank lines as this is how paragraph breaks should usually be coded. Deleting them all is unlikely to be an optimal solution or, indeed, to solve anything at all.

Comment: In fact, you seem to have a lot of blank lines starting at line 531. Do you have an `\end{document}` anywhere? If not, the compile will take an infinite amount of time, excepting that the site will stop it after some finite period.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, there were a lot of errors due to mathematic equations, I tried to correct them.

Example:  `$$ K_e=3*x+1$$`
 this one is false, the right one  is:   `$K_e=3*x+1$` or
`\[K_e=3*x+1\]`. When there are a lot of errors, the document cannot be compiled.